# Help to calculate eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How do you calculate eigenvectors on this matrix?
\begin{pmatrix}4&1&-3\\ 1&2&-1\\ -3&-1&3\end{pmatrix}
I found the eigenvalues: 
Lamba1 = 6.94338, 
Lambda2 = 1.60909,
Lambda3 = 0.447525,
but every time I tried to get the eigenvectors, I get a zero vector for each lambda. I used row reduction and Cramer's rule. Now I am lost. I don't know what to do anymore.

Also on a website that calculates eigenvectors for you, I obtained
v1 = [-1.16825, -0.438618, 1],  v2= [-2.64178, 9.31626, 1], v3=[0.810038, 0.122361, 1]. I understand that if I fixed the last value to 1 for each vector, I get the other two by solving my equations. But what is the logic behind it? How do you go from a zero vector to those one?

Any help will be really appreciated!!! thank you.

Comment: The best thing is to show your steps. Most likely there is some algebraic mistake in the process.

Comment: Cramer’s rule is going to be of no use to you because the coefficient matrix $A-\lambda I$ in the eigenvector equation is by definition singular—the denominator in Cramer’s rule will be $0$. You’re solving a homogeneous equation, so you should expect to get $0$ as a solution, but you’re looking for non-zero solutions. Do you remember how to solve an underdetermined system?

Comment: ama, why don't you try this one first: \begin{pmatrix}4&1&1\\ 1&4&1\\ 1&1&4\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Alright, I understand now! I looked at the underdetermined system and did the simple matrix, it showed me well the dependence and how to solve it. Thank you all for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues and eigenvectors are really unpleasant for this one. On the other hand, maybe you were told to "diagonalize" the matrix. In that case, the reasonable thing to do is **congruence** diagonalization, for your **symmetric** matrix $H,$ find nonsingular matrix $P$ such that $P^T HP = D$ is diagonal. We can actually arrange that $\det P = \pm 1.$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 5 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 3 &  - 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ D_0 = H $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 3 &  - 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
 - 3 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 5 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 3 &  - 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 7 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 3 &  - 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm still very confused by your matrices. I was not asked to use anything specific. So I tried to follow the normal way to resolve this. I did (Matrix - Lamba*IdentityMatrix)*eigenvector = 0. Then I have 3 equations with three unknowns. From what I'm getting this system is dependent, so it has an infinite number of solution. So I may express two unknowns in function of the third one. Fix the third one as a constant and solve the other two. Does that seem correct?